# How to make a button add by 2?

Tags: java, android, button, crash

**I try this code out for the app I'm making. But this code crashes on the app when I click the button. How do I make the button add by 2 without the app crashing.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      final TextView view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); //textview


      final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); //button


     }
public void tkdngreen(View view) {
    TextView view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String num1 = "1" ;
    String num2 = "1" ;
    int num3 = Integer.parseInt(num1);
    int num4 = Integer.parseInt(num2);


    view1.setText(num3 + num4);
    } 
}
```

Comment: How can your app crash when you press the button? You are neither setting up a click listener for your button, nor calling your function. It therefore could only crash while starting. Which would mean you are looking for ids that aren't existing in your xml. (which is missing from this question, as well as your error output)

Answer (score 1):

`num3 + num4` returns an `int` and the `setText` that expects an `int` is expecting it to be a string resource.

You need `view1.setText(String.valueof(num3 + num4));` to convert the `int` to a string first.

```
view1.setText(String.valueof(num3 + num4)); // this works, but still doesn't double
```

Comment: In the above code, that part/function isn't even called.

Comment: I would guess he's using the android:onClick attribute, but who knows, there's a lot missing here, I made some assumptions and this is the most glaring mistake.

Comment: Umm I tried the solution view1.setText(String.valueof(num3 + num4)); and this works but dosent double the amount still ?

Answer (score 0):

Does it R.id.button) included in activity_main.xml?
Otherwise, please attach crashing log and other source.
When I see only provided source, it doesn't have problem.